# Equilibrium of a system of charges

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

> Suppose three positively charged particles are constrained to move on
> a fixed circular track. If the charges were all equal, an equilibrium
> arrangement would obviously be a symmetrical one with the particles
> spaced 120◦ apart around the circle. Suppose that two of the charges
> are equal and the equilibrium arrangement is such that these two
> charges are 90◦ apart rather than 120◦. What is the relative magnitude
> of the third charge?

This exercise does not seems to be so much difficult, and it is easy to solve it by considering the vectors on each particle. But the problem is, trying to answer the question more fast than using vectors, i thought that we could use $V=0$ expression. But with this, i got the wrong answer.

Now, i tried to use this equation because i thought that, in a system of charges, when the system is in equilibrium the potential energy vanish (yes, the potential energy, not the derivative). Why it can't be applied here? It is because we have a tension force by the circle?

$$V = q^2/ r \sqrt{2} + 2qQ/x = 0$$

And we can find x, the distance between the particles easily by trigonometry.

Comment: > *when the system is in equilibrium the potential energy vanish* This is not true, unless you define the state of zero of potential energy to be that with the equilibrium configuration.Which would be useless if you're trying to find that equilibrium configuration in the first place. Here, you seek value of third charge that makes the system be in equilibrium, so you're seeking an attribute of the equilibrium configuration.Equilibrium is characterized by equilibrium of forces, or equivalently, by the condition that potential energy differential is zero when slightly changing the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

By 'in equilibrium', it sounds as though the forces should be in equilibrium, i.e. the resultant force is only directed towards or away from the centre of the circle (so that a charge would not move around the circle).

So you'll need to use the force equation $F=\frac{kQ_1Q_2}{r^2}$

Your question seems to mean this as $V$ isn't zero in the first example, but the forces will be balanced in the way described above.

Comment: Yes, but i want to know why we can't apply V=0 in this case, and in another exercises we can. Precisely.